# How to put a set data type into Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data class of A with a set of strings as the property. How do I put it into the Firestore?

`data class A(
    val str: set<String> = emptySet()
)`

Answer (score 1):

A mathematical set is best mapped to an array in Cloud Firestore, which you then manipulate with the `array-union` and `array-remove` operators, and query using `array-contains`. These operators ensure that each value can occur only once in the array, which is required to make it mimic a set.

See:

- [Better Arrays in Cloud Firestore!](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html)